# PHP DataContractJsonSerializer format

Tags: php, datetime, unix

I have unix timestamp value in milleseconds like below.

```
        $timezone = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', '4-5-2015 8:07:27');

        $requiredJsonFormat = sprintf(
            '\/Date(%s%s)\/',
            $dateTime->format('U') * 1000,
            $dateTime->format('O')
        );

        echo $requiredJsonFormat;
```

The above output will be.

`\/Date(1428192447000+0800)\/`

How do I make the above code to show the output like below.

`\/Date(1428192447278+0800)\/"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to output the microseconds as well.
According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) this is only possible for *DateTime* objects if you initiate it with microseconds.

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s:u', '4-5-2015 8:07:27:278');
```

When you've don that, you can now get it as well.

```
$requiredJsonFormat = sprintf(
    '\/Date(%s%s%s)\/',
    $dateTime->format('U'),
    $dateTime->format('u') / 1000,
    $dateTime->format('O')
);
```